# Meeting the Big Five!

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

> 1. I am the biggest one!
> 2. Someone uses my horn as medicine
> 3. I was slaughtered for my skin.
> 4. My heart is my King.
> 5. I am dotted.

What would be no. 5's grateful answer after facing a ban?

Hint 1:

> The big five faces The Ban under The Moon!

Hint 2:

> No. 1 would say: "Spasiba"

Comment: Normally, I'd ignore it, but in a puzzle, each word can be significant.

Comment: @Chris Cudmore I know, and appreciate any comments:-)

Comment: @Enigma: Is this related to the sanctions against Russia (facing a ban) because of Eastern-Ukraine?

Comment: @Gamow I just added a hint

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first layer of this enigmatic puzzle is centered around

> the big five African game animals,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_five_game

1. I am the biggest one!

   > The African elephant
2. Someone use my horn as medicine

   > The Rhinoceros
3. I was slaughtered for my skin.

   > The African buffalo
4. My heart is my King.

   > The African lion (alluding at King Richard Lionheart)
5. I am dotted.

   > The African leopard

In the second layer of the puzzle, the big five are

> the  big five Nations of the United Nations Security Council

1. I am the biggest one!

   > The biggest country is **Russia**
2. Someone uses my horn as medicine

   > **Chinese** medicine is well-known for using Rhinoceros horns
3. I was slaughtered for my skin.

   > In the **USA**, buffalos were slaughtered in the 19th century.
4. My heart is my King.

   > The **UK** is the only kingdom among these five nations.
5. I am dotted.

   > This leaves **France** as the fifth nation.
   >  (Perhaps dotted, because of the French trémas and accents.)

Facing a ban refers to

> Ban Ki-Moon, the Secretary-General of the United Nations

What would be no. 5's grateful answer after facing a ban?

> France's grateful answer to Ban Ki-Moon will of course be **"Merci"**.

Comment: Good start, but you fail to see the enigma here...

Comment: So the one who faced a ban isn't Rand al thor? :D

Comment: @Enigma: Is this problem in the same spirit as your puzzles from spring 2015, which consisted of several layers? If yes, then I would like to ask you for a hint for the next layer. Is the "ban" in your problem the South African leopard hunting ban? And is the grateful answerer "no. 5" indeed a leopard?

Comment: South Africa is a dead end.

Comment: If it indeed is a double layer, what could be the big five of the other layer?

Comment: Egyptian mythology? Ra is dotted, Anubis weighs the heart and is associated with the pharaoh's burial, Isis is a healer with cow's horns.

Comment: Biggest countries in Africa, maybe? By population, that'd be Nigeria, Ethiopia, Egypt, the DRC, and South Africa; by area, Algeria, the DRC, Sudan, Libya, and Chad.

Comment: If it wasn't specifically a grateful answer, I would guess the leopard said "But I'm not a cheetah!" after being banned for foul play

Comment: @Gamow "facing a ban" is an enigmatic twist...

Comment: @Enigma: Is the enigma related to the soccer game in Disney's "Bedknobs and Broomsticks"? I vaguely recall a soccer play with a lion, a rhinoceros, an elephant. The "ban" could be a yellow/red card.

Comment: @Gamow No, I would rather follow your other idea you had previously...

Comment: You are so close... If you combine the big five, what would the leopard say?

Comment: I just added another hint

Comment: No, the leopard is dotted. It speaks french only because that is the only available option left

Comment: I was also thinking of King Richard Lionheart

Comment: I have Richard Lionheart  under the animal lion (first layer).

Comment: Yeah I saw that. But that was my initial link between lion and UK:-)

Comment: @Gamow By the way, it is a very nice formatted answer. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

Not quite there yet ...

1 I am the biggest one!

> Asia, the largest continent

2 Someone uses my horn as medicine

> Africa, with the horn of Africa being referred to

3 I was slaughtered for my skin.

> America, with the "red skins" slaughtered

4 My heart is my King.

> Europe, where the title of King was, and still is sometimes, prevalent

5 I am dotted.

> Oceania, with its many islands

So

> They face ban ki-moon (united nations leader) ? But what would oceania say if grateful for the UN?

Comment: You are getting closer...

Comment: Mmmmm .... Something about climate change? A word or sentence in one of the languages from Oceania?

Comment: Please add some reasoning behind the clues

Comment: I did add some explanations in my answer, for each of the five clues. But I bet that's not what you're talking about ...

Comment: The reasoning is good, you only missed on who is the big five. You need to combine two layers to get it right...

Comment: I just added another hint